Having trouble hosting a telegrambot in js to Render
I am trying to host my telegram bot on Render. I am kinda new to programming so I apologize for any stupid code.
Im using VScode as editor and integrated terminal
When i host the bot locally with npm run dev through nodemon, everything works fine, but on Render I am treated with :
error code

/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1501
reject(new FetchError(request to ${request.url} failed, reason: ${err.message}, 'system', err));
^
FetchError: request to https://api.telegram.org/bot7086599593:[REDACTED]/setMyCommands failed, reason:
at ClientRequest. (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1501:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:500:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:540:9)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
type: 'system',
errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
code: 'ETIMEDOUT'
}


I am new to all of the coding world, so I am not sure what I should attach, so here is my index.js and package.json
index.js
const { Telegraf, Extra  } = require('telegraf');
const bot = new Telegraf('<My token>');
const { timeOptions, levOption } = require('./options.js');
const { DateTime } = require('luxon');
const { translate } = require('google-translate-api-browser');
const keep_alive = require('./keep_alive.js')











// get time
function getCurrentTime(timezone) {
    return DateTime.now().setZone(timezone).toLocaleString(DateTime.TIME_24_SIMPLE);
}
const russiaTime = getCurrentTime('Europe/Moscow');
const indonesiaTime = getCurrentTime('Asia/Singapore');

// make words
let generate;
import('random-words').then(module => {
    generate = module.generate;
});




//commands 



bot.telegram.setMyCommands([
            { command: 'start', description: 'say hello' },
            { command: 'time', description: 'get times' },
            { command: 'lev', description: 'lev command' },
        ]);






//start
bot.start(ctx => {
    ctx.reply(`some text`);
    ctx.replyWithSticker('CAACAgIAAxkBAAEE4eNmJSOk67FOoiMUqzY-WHOh_2Pm8QACFQADwzrpMIiABX8lwyAmNAQ');
    });



// lev options
bot.command('lev', (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply('some text', levOption)
    });

// lev reply
bot.action('levText', (ctx) => {
    let randomAmount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1 ;
    let randomSentence = generate({ exactly: randomAmount, join: " " });
    translate(`${randomSentence}`, { to: "ru" })
  .then(res => {
    ctx.reply(`some text, \n${res.text}`);
  })
    });

//time options
bot.command('time', ctx => {
    ctx.reply(`some text?`, timeOptions)
    });
   
    //time reply
bot.action("israel", ctx => {
    ctx.reply(`some text, ${russiaTime}`);
    });
bot.action("indonesia", ctx => {
    ctx.reply(`some text, ${indonesiaTime}`);
    });
bot.action("russia", ctx => {
    ctx.reply(`some text, ${russiaTime}`);
    });
bot.action("allcountries", ctx => {
    ctx.reply(`some text, ${russiaTime},\nа some text ${indonesiaTime}`);
    });
   
    
    
    













bot.launch();


package.json

{
  "name": "tgbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "google-translate-api-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "luxon": "^3.4.4",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "random-words": "^2.0.1",
    "telegraf": "^4.16.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/SDX24/ovr-bot.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/SDX24/ovr-bot/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/SDX24/ovr-bot#readme",
  "engines": {
    "node": "20.12.2"
  }
}




FYI: I the repository I am using is private, as there are my telegram bot tokens and I have removed some unnessesary comments and texts as they are written in a different language and shouldnt be affecting anything.
Thank you in advance!
I have tried to change versions of node-fetch and node as well as telegraf, tried implementing chatGPT written error catching and retry logic but am still getting the same issue.
I assume that the issue maybe related to me using telegraf as it has been one of the error parts when i tested previous code versions, but I think I fixed it.

Many countries have blocked Telegram. So:

You will may not be deploy your code successfull, I tried to use server in HongKong and Singapore, they failed, but Indian work :))

Use VPNs which can hide your ip. Telegram's website can find your main ip and will not allow you to use its features.

=> So you have to use different safe VPNs  from creating new bot until you finally get your bot's api key.


See more here https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/1825
